# How to count records matching multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to count records matching multiple criteria

Comment: On the surface it looks like the following two-step process will give the result you need: add a Cluster column to the first sheet using vlookup to get the cluster from the second sheet; create a pivot table with Range and Series on the rows, and Cluster on the columns.

Comment: @MattClarke.. thanks for your suggestion. I could create a pivot table. But I dont know how to use vlookup to get cluster for corresponding countries. Can you please tell how to do that. Apart from that rest is fine now :)

Comment: @MattClarke I could use the lookup as well. thanks a lot.

Comment: What's happened with the last edit? OP deleted almost the whole text?!?

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,A1003,$B$2:$B$1000,B1003,$D$2:$D$1000,D1003)`

This is a SUMIFS formula, where the first range of column E we’ve defined is the thing to add up, then we have pairs of criteria range and criteria in columns A, B and C.

I’m suggesting that column A is range, column B is series, column C is country, column D is the cluster (see below) and column E is the number we’re adding up.

MattClarke is spot on, the first job to do is to map the countries into clusters using a *VLOOKUP*, place that formula in column D.

The formula above assumes it is operating on a summary table starting underneath the main data set at row 1003. You’ll need unique values to reference in the range criteria.

So much easier if we could share a spreadsheet :) make sure you click the function building button left of the formula bar, for an explanation of *SUMIFS*.